# Intercepting the Stop button on browsers when dialog is popped up

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that loads 100 thumbnails in a grid, similar to Google image search.

This can take a few seconds for the whole page and the images to load fully.

Sometimes, depending on circumstances, I popup a dialog box when they first view the page (on document.ready), using Jquery UI Dialog.

Dialogs and popup boxes frequently have the functionality where the Escape key closes them.

However, there is a slight problem I've come into.

If I popup a dialog on document ready, and the user quickly presses Escape to close the dialog, the browser is catching the escape key and if the thumbnails are still loading it cancels the load, and then those images display as broken links.

I understand that the escape key is basically doing a browser 'stop'. But, is there anyway I can 'disable' this if I had poped up a dialog?

I've tried intercepting the keypress, but it seems its impossible to prevent the browser from doing its thing, when escape is pressed and its still loading. Even if I send a preventDefault or stopPropagation from the dialogs keypress event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach yourself to the document keydown event and prevent the default behavior.

```
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
     if (event.keyCode === 27) {
          event.preventDefault();
     }
}
```

Comment: Damn I was so hoping browsers finally implemented a `KEYCODE` global object with speaking names.. ;)

Comment: Nah, it doesn't :( If you use jQuery UI thought you can access such a global object: http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.ui.keyCode/

Comment: Ah ha, thanks. Had tried keypress(), and it didnt work in there, keydown is the place to do it :)